# Why is property not allowed to be declared in comma separated var?

Tags: javascript

Might be really stupid question but all this time I thought that it was okay to declare anything in comma separated var, like so:-

```
var x = 2, y = "hello world";
```

But I was surprised to see that this was not possible.

```
var obj = {};
var x = 2, y = "hello world", obj.myProp = "good bye";
```

or this:-

```
var obj = {};
var x = 2, y = "hello world", obj["myProp"] = "good bye";
```

Anyone know why this is?

Comment: `var` is for declaring a variable. `obj.myProp = "good bye"` or `obj["myProp"] = "good bye"` is not a declaration. It's an assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the 'obj' is an Object and it is already defined.
when you are adding property, again you are assigning it to 'var' which is not correct.

Comment: This actually makes sense. When I do:-

`obj = {};
 
x = 2, y = "hello world", obj.myProp = "good bye";`

it actually works, although I don't think this is a good practice.

Answer (score 3):

When you execute the code, the error you would get is

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

Because `var` is the variable declaration statement and in the `var` statement, only valid variable names are allowed. `obj.myProp` and `obj["myProp"]` are clearly invalid variable names, as `.`, `"`, `[` and `]` are not allowed in a variable's name. You can read more about the variable names in the ECMA 5.1 Standard Specification's [Identifier Names and Identifiers](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6) section.

Also, you cannot declare `obj.myProp` in the current scope, as `myProp` is a property of `obj`. If you want to define a variable on `obj`, simply define it separately.

If you really want to assign all the values in a single line, then separate the declaration from the initialization like this

```
var obj = {}, x, y;
x = 2, y = "hello world", obj.myProp = "good bye";
```

Comment: Probably also worth mentioning that var is for declaring stuff in the current context. Declaring a property on an an object as a local var doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Though that is correct, OP can't get past the Syntax error.

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense now but @SPEC was first to point that out so I'll have to mark that as correct one. Sorry. :(

Answer (score 1):

Because of Declaring a variable more than once in same block.

like

```
Int32 a; // Declare a variable(a) type of Int32.
```

Again declare a different variable (b) and initialize variable (a)

```
Int32 b,a=10 ; // a variable is declared more than once.
```

Our Programming rules :: we can't declare same variable more than once with same name in same block. it's quite simple but logical